# jQuery Pretty Print add content during runtime

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to add content at a prettyprint element without having to wipeout all content.
The following code works, but it deletes all content and refills it with the new.
This is not what I need.

```
$('#console').html(content);
$('.prettyprinted').removeClass('prettyprinted');
prettyPrint();
```

What I do need is the following;

```
$('#console').prepend(content);
$('.prettyprinted').removeClass('prettyprinted');
prettyPrint();
```

unfortunately using prepend on a prettyprinted element doesn't work correctly, which makes sense, the content that already was in the element has been initialized before.
So i'm wondering if there is a simular plugin that has a function like addContent or something.

Answer (score -1):

If `prettyPrint` is a plugin, then you should look if it includes some method to prepend as you want. If not, then we need to know exatly what `prettyPrint` is doing before knowing what else to do.